# ConnectionTimeout in Volley Networking

Tags: android-volley, connection-timeout

Could anybody  please tell me how to set connection timeout using volley library for about 15 seconds.??

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the retry policy [DefaultRetryPolicy](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy.html), something like this:

```
volleyRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(YOUR_TIME_HERE, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```